# How to use r kmeans cluster vector to repaint plot?

Tags: k-means

km = kmeans(FourA,3)
km$cluster
[1] 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 2 ...

How do I use the km$cluster vector to create 3 new arrays so that I can plot the graph with the three clusters using a different character/color?

Answer (score 0):

For your reference

```
x <- rbind(matrix(rnorm(100, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2),
           matrix(rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 0.3), ncol = 2))
cl <- kmeans(x, 3, nstart = 25)
plot(x, col = cl$cluster)
points(cl$centers, col = 1:3, pch = 8)
```